# parallel R execution problem in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am using doSMP as a parallel backend in Windows 7, with R 2.12.2. I incur in an error, and would like to understand the likely cause. Here is some sample code to reproduce the error.

```
require(foreach)
require(doSMP)
require(data.table)
wrk <- startWorkers(workerCount = 2)
registerDoSMP(wrk)
DF = data.table(x=c("b","b","b","a","a"),v=rnorm(5))
setkey(DF,x)
foreach( i=1:2)  %dopar% {
    DF[J("a"),]
}
```

The error message is

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "J""
```

Comment: I'll ask the obvious Q - what is `J()` I have run your code and get the same error on a Linux box with R 2.13-0-alpha and I can't find `J()` anywhere on that system.

Comment: this is the same question as Gavin, but when you call `DF[J("a"),]` what is J?

Comment: Ah, ignore that, I see that DF[J("a"),] works when not in the `foreach()` wrapper so it must be something particular to data.table. Will investigate more.

Comment: ok, J is a data.table function. I see ;) It looks like the spawned worker R instances need to have the data.table package loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I asked Revolution computing, and Steve Weller (of RC) replied:

> The problem is a R scoping issue. By
>   default, foreach() will look for
>   variables defined in it's own
>   'environment'. Any objects defined
>   outside of it's scope need to be
>   explicitly passed to it via the
>   '.export' argument.
>
> In your case, you will need to modify
>   your 'foreach()' call to pass in the
>   objects 'DF' and 'J':

```
...

foreach(i=1:2, .export=c("DF","J")) %dopar% {
...
```

I haven't tried either solution yet, but I trust both JD and RC...

Comment: I don't think you need `"DF"` in there. I get a warning if I use your line: `already exporting variable(s): DF` If you leave out `"DF"` it works without warning.

Comment: Since your foreach loop needs to use the `data.table` package, you should use `.packages`, as in @JD Long's answer, and then exporting isn't necessary.  Exporting may also hurt your performance since I believe it will serialize the whole package along with the function.  Loading a package is the best way to "export" functions to the workers.

Answer (score 8):

I've not used doSMP, but I did some digging around and it looks like [this post](http://forums.revolutionanalytics.com/archive/index.php/t-976.html) gets at a similar issue.

so it looks like you should be able to do:

```
foreach( i=1:2, .packages="data.table")  %dopar% {
    DF[J("a"),]
}
```

I can't test as I don't have a Windows machine handy.